# How does echo off and on are executes in same batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, adb

How does echo off and on working in the following script and what if we want to use `echo off` at some places of batch script let's say outside loops and `echo on` inside loops how should we do that

If I try to use `@`instead of globally make it off by `@echo off`.Do I have to place '@' in every line?

Here the following code:

```
@echo off
set select=package:com.google.ar.core
set "str=%select%"
set "string1=%str::=" & set "string2=%"     

@echo on
echo %select%
echo %string2%
@echo off
echo.
```

Here what the output looks

```
echo package:com.google.ar.core
package:com.google.ar.core

echo com.google.ar.core
com.google.ar.core
```

Please help in understanding the execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic points first: you need to differentiate between *echo a command* when it is executed in a Batch file vs. the *output of a command*. The output of a command is what the command *generates* and it is always displayed on the screen (unless there is an output redirection, but that is another story).

The "echo of a command" is a *trace* of the command that will be executed. If "echo is on", the command itself will be displayed before it is executed.

If "echo is on" you may *cancel* the echo of a command if you precede it by `@`.

You should note that the echo of commands happen when the commands are *parsed*, that is, reviewed before executed, and that several commands enclosed in parentheses are parsed as a whole. This means that changing the "echo" status *inside a code block* have not effect for the commands in the block: the echo will have the same status as when the block begins. Of course, if the echo status is changed in the block, it will work for the commands *after* the block.

```
@echo off
rem "Echo" is off here; commands are not echoed
rem This command does not generate any output
echo This command generate output

echo on
rem "Echo" is on here; commands are echoed
rem This command does not generate any output
echo This command generate output

@rem This command is preceded by "@" so it is not echoed
@echo This command is also not echoed, but produce an output


@echo off
rem "Echo" is off here; commands are not echoed

rem The block below is *parsed* entirely before executed
(
   echo This command produces output
   echo on
   rem Previous command set "Echo" on, but this block was parsed already
   rem so the commands placed here are *not* echoed either
   echo Command that produce output
)

rem The echo is on here
```

Comment: The only thing missing is an explanation of how when ECHO is ON, each FOR loop iteration echoes the DO block with the values of the FOR variables expanded. Also the iteration echo can be controlled from within the same code block, unlike code that is not within a FOR loop.